# MySQL query where column may be missing

Tags: mysql

I have a Microsoft stored procedure that queries two MySQL databases using OpenQuery. The two MySQL databases should be have the same schemas, so I can run the same query on both.

However, we will soon alter the MySQL schemas, and add a column to a table. But the two MySQL databases won't happen at the same time, and I don't know the exact date of the releases.

I therefore want to write the query so that if the new column exists, then I use it in my select. If not, then I use a default value.

Is this possible? (That is have a query that handles differences in the table schema?)

(Not to be confused with 'coelesce' where the field definitely exists, but is simply null.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'your table name' 
          AND COLUMN_NAME = 'the column name you want to check for'
```

If the above returns a value, your column is there.  If not, then run your alternative SELECT statement

Updated statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM OPENQUERY(servername, 'SELECT * 
                                       FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
                                       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''database name'' 
                                             AND TABLE_NAME = ''your table name'' 
                                             AND COLUMN_NAME = ''the column name you want to check for'' ))
```

Comment: thank you. Now I just need to find how to do the logic based on whether it returns a value. I thought of count(*). Depending on 0 or 1. Or is there a better way? thanks!

Comment: @user2708232 You can use the IF EXISTS statement in the SQL Server context.  See the updated code above

Comment: Thank you! I will figure it out from here. :)